# Redux-thunk: action creator automatically called

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have reducer:

```
import sliderInitialConfig from '../fixures';

export default (sliderConfig = sliderInitialConfig, action) => {
    const {type, payload} = action;
    switch(type) {
        case "SELECT_CONFIG":
            console.log(sliderConfig);
            return sliderConfig.filter(item => item.id === payload);

        default:
            return sliderConfig;
    }
}
```

I have action creator (using redux-thunk)

```
export const selectConfig = (id) => dispatch => {
  dispatch({type: "SELECT_CONFIG", payload: id})
};
```

I have a part of JSX code, where I am using AC.

```
 {
    sliderElements.map(item =>
       <li
       key={item.id}
       className="btn"
       onClick={this.props.selectConfig(item.id)}
       >
       {item.device}
       </li>
  )
 }
```

So, when I load the project in the browser, this AC automatically called, and instead of array of elements, I received empty array, as here:

```
{sliderElements: Array(4), fetchUser: ƒ, handleToken: ƒ, submitSurvey: ƒ, scrollMovement: ƒ, …}
sliderElements.js:7 (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: {id: 1, device: "Apple iMac", image: "/static/media/mac_monitor.931c27aa.svg"}1: {id: 2, device: "Apple Macbook Pro", image: "/static/media/mackbook_pro.c9315d2b.png"}2: {id: 3, device: "MSI GP72VR 7RFX", image: "/static/media/iphone_X.bebbd7bc.jpg"}3: {id: 4, device: "Iphone X", image: "/static/media/msi_laptop.8190feed.jpg"}length: 4__proto__: Array(0)
sliderElements.js:7 [{…}]0: {id: 1, device: "Apple iMac", image: "/static/media/mac_monitor.931c27aa.svg"}length: 1__proto__: Array(0)
sliderElements.js:7 []
sliderElements.js:7 []
BlockFive.js:14 {sliderElements: Array(0), fetchUser: ƒ, handleToken: ƒ, submitSurvey: ƒ, scrollMovement: ƒ, …}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       <li
       key={item.id}
       className="btn"
       onClick={this.props.selectConfig(item.id)}
       >
       {item.device}
       </li>
```

Here, you are *calling* the selectConfig function.  You want to *pass* this function to the onClick prop, but not call it.  You also want to define the value to be used as it's input.  There are 2 main ways to do this;

1. Curry;

   ```
   getSelectConfig(id) => () => this.props.selectConfig(id)

   ...

   onClick={this.getSelectConfig(item.id)}
   ```
2. Binding;

   ```
   onClick={this.selectConfig.bind(this, item.id)}
   ```